# My left and right eye have a consistent, clear difference in color perception. Why?

Tags: eye, vision, ophthalmology, optometry

Myself, my brother, and a friend of mine all have noticed independently that our left and right eyes perceive colour differently from the other eye. As compared to my vision with both eyes open, my left eye sees things in a noticeably cooler palette while my right eye sees things in a noticeably warmer palette. This has been detectable since my early childhood, some 24 years or so, thus not a new development of any kind, at least in my case.

We have each ask our relevant medical professionals why this might be throughout the years, and the answers have ranged from "I don't know" to "I've never heard of that happening." The latter I have always found a bit surprising.

We wear corrective lenses for various vision issues, I assume it is related to that some how, but the mechanism in particular eludes me. I also feel like maybe this is true for everyone and we just happened to notice it.

- My brother and I both have substantial astigmatism, the parameters of which vary significantly between each eye.
- My friend has astigmatism in one eye only.
- They both report the difference being between cooler and warmer palettes, though I don't recall if their variations correlate to the same eyes in terms of weak and dominant. My dominant eye is my right (the warmer one).
- Speaking only for myself, the effect is present regardless of whether I am wearing my glasses or not.
- Speaking only for myself, the effect has not gotten noticeably stronger or weaker with time.

I'm not concerned that this is a big deal, and it does not bother me at this time, just curious that the three of us have had this experience without hearing about it anywhere else, and without our professionals knowing what we're talking about.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-colors-look-slightly-different-when-viewed-out-of-each-eye-separately

Comment: @CareyGregory Just to be clear, does this first (most popular) answer imply that it's strictly a bit of a temporal parlor trick; that it's merely the cone fatigue of me closing my eye and then switching to it? Because that wouldn't explain the consistent alternation, i.e. both eyes should be able to show the same variation, but they don't. The second answer on that page is more in line with what is happening and what I personal theorized.

Comment: I think the second answer by Martin Oguzie is probably correct.

Comment: See a very similar post on Biology.StackExchange: [Why do I see different hues of colors between each of my eyes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/42344/16866):